# Yacc Grammar not reducing the last literal of the input correctly

Tags: grammar, yacc, lex

This is a code for generating a 3 address code for the arithmetic expression.

The problem I am facing is that my grammar is able to read the input correctly till the last literal. But unable to reduce the last literal just before the '\n'

example : x = 1 + 2 * 3 - 4
1,2,3 are read properly. Even the minus. When it reads the 4 it is able to reduce the grammar for 2 steps. Then gives an error.

I Have put the print statements for help. This is the whole code. Problem while reading last literal:

```
x -> IDEN | NUM | ....  
f -> x  
t -> f (This doesn't happen)
```

icg.y

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int temp_reg_num = 0;
    void print_three_address_code(char* text1,char oper,char* text2)
    {
        printf("t%d = %s %c %s\n",temp_reg_num,text1,oper,text2);
    }   
%}

%token IDEN, NUM, FLOAT 
%union {
    char* text;
}

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'

%%
s : IDEN '=' e '\n' {
    printf("start\n");
    if($3.text == NULL)
        printf("%s = t%d\n",$1.text,temp_reg_num-1);
    else
        printf("%s = %s\n",$1.text,$3.text);
    return 0;
}
;
e : e '+' t {
    printf("e -> e + t\n");
    char temp[5];
    print_three_address_code($1.text,'+',$3.text);
    sprintf(temp,"t%d",temp_reg_num++);
    $$.text = copy_string(temp);
}
  | e '-' t {
    printf("e -> e - t\n");
    char temp[5];
    print_three_address_code($1.text,'-',$3.text);
    sprintf(temp,"t%d",temp_reg_num++);
    $$.text = copy_string(temp);
}
  | t {
    printf("e -> t\n");
    $$.text = copy_string($1.text);
}
;
t : t '*' f {
    printf("t -> t * f\n");
    char temp[5];
    print_three_address_code($1.text,'*',$3.text);
    sprintf(temp,"t%d",temp_reg_num++);
    $$.text = copy_string(temp);
}
  | t '/' f {
    printf("t -> t / f\n");
    char temp[5];
    print_three_address_code($1.text,'/',$3.text);
    sprintf(temp,"t%d",temp_reg_num++);
    $$.text = copy_string(temp);
}
  | f {
    printf("t -> f\n");
    $$.text = copy_string($1.text);
}
;
f : f '^' x {
    printf("f -> f ^ x\n");
    char temp[5];
    print_three_address_code($1.text,'^',$3.text);
    sprintf(temp,"t%d",temp_reg_num++);
    $$.text = copy_string(temp);
}
  | x {
    printf("f -> x\n");
    $$.text = copy_string($1.text);
    printf("Why syntax error??");
}
;
x : '(' s ')' {}
      | NUM {
    printf("x -> NUM\n");
    $$.text = copy_string($1.text);
}
      | IDEN {
    printf("x -> IDEN\n");
    $$.text = copy_string($$.text,$1.text);
}
      | FLOAT {
    printf("x -> FLOAT\n");
    $$.text = copy_string($1.text);
}
      | '-' x {
    printf("x -> - x\n");
    $$.text = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen($2.text)+2));
    $$.text[0] = '-';
    strcat($$.text,$2.text);
}
;
%%

main()
{
    printf("Enter your expression : ");
    yyparse();
}
yyerror()
{
    printf("Syntax Error\n");
}
yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}
```

icg.l

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include"y.tab.h"
    char* copy_string(char* fromstring)  
    {
        char* tostring = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(fromstring)+1));  
        strcpy(tostring,fromstring);  
        return tostring;  
    }
%}

iden [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_]*  
%%  
[0-9]+ {  
    yylval.text = copy_string(yytext);  
    return NUM;  
}
[0-9]+[.][0-9]+ {  
    yylval.text = copy_string(yytext);  
    return FLOAT;  
}
{iden} {  
    yylval.text = copy_string(yytext);  
    return IDEN;  
}  
[+] {  
    return '+';  
}  
[-] {  
    return '-';  
}  
[*] {  
    return '*';  
}  
[/] {  
    return '/';  
}  
['^'] {  
    return '^';  
}  
[=] {  
    return '=';  
}  
'\n' {  
    return '\n';  
}  
. {}  
%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that syntax error because of this rule:

```
'\n' { return '\n'; }
```

Flex does not consider `'` to be in any way special, so that rule will (only) match the three character sequence <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>. That doesn't appear in your input, so the rule which requires a `\n` will not succeed, and when you provide an end-of-file (or the file ends, if you are reading from a file), then you'll get a syntax error.

So what you should write is:

```
\n { return '\n'; }
```

Also,

```
['^']
```

does not only match a `^`. It also matches a `'`, because, as above, `'` is not in any way special and so the character class consists of three characters, one of which is repeated. To match exactly the character `^`, use double-quotes (which are special):

```
"^"
```

(However, `"\n"` would not work, unless what you wanted to match was precisely a `\` followed by an `n`. Just `\n` is what you want.)

You can actually simplify all of those single character rules into a single rule:

```
[-+*/^()=\n]   { return yytext[0]; }
```

I included `(` and `)` although they were not in your icg.l file because you use them in your grammar.

However, the rule you use them in is not correct:

```
x : '(' s ')' {}
```

since `s` is an assignment. That would allow

```
x = 1 + (y = 2 * 3) - 4
```

but not allow the more normal

```
x = 1 + (2 * 3) - 4
```

What you want is:

```
x : '(' e ')' { $$ = $2; }
```

There are various other errors in your grammar, including:

- missing `#include <string.h>` header (for `strlen`)
- missing declarations for `yylex`, `yyerror` and `copy_string`
- incorrect (or more accurately, antiquated) prototypes for `main` and `yyerror`. "Modern C" -- as in, for the last 30 years or so -- prefers explicit return types, and since C99 (1999) requires them.
- an instance of `copy_string` with two arguments instead of one, which is undefined behaviour. (It would have been flagged as an error if you'd provided a declaration for `copy_string`.)

Your icg.y file was processed without complaint by Berkeley yacc (`byacc`) but `bison` will not process it even in yacc compatibility mode. The problem is your use of `$1.text` and your failure to declare the tags of your terminals and non-terminals. If you are declaring a `union` type, you should provide tag declarations both for your terminals:

```
%token <text> NUM IDEN FLOAT
```

and your non-terminals (or at least the ones which have semantic values):

```
%type <text> s e t f x
```

Then you can remove all the `.text` selectors from your actions, since `bison` (and even `byacc`) will know which selector to use. Declaring token tags makes your parser type-safe, or at least less type-unsafe, and it is also usually more readable.

Finally, you need to work on your memory management. You never `free()` any of the strings you allocated in `string_copy`, so you are gradually building up quite a bit of leaked memory. Furthermore, you copy in many cases where it is unnecessary; for example, in the unit rule:

```
x : NUM { $$.text = copy_string($1.text); }
```

the copy is completely unnecessary, since `$1` is about to be popped off the parser stack, and the string it references will never be used again. So you're just unnecessarily leaking a copy. Much cleaner would be

```
x : NUM { $$ = $1; }
```

but that is actually unnecessary because it is the default action.

Changing the unit productions won't stop the other memory leaks; in the productions which actually do something with the semantic values other than pass them through, you'll still need to manually `free` the copied strings if you don't need them any longer (which seems to be the case in all your semantic actions). Or you'll need to figure out how to free them later if you will need them later.

You can use the built-in tracing feature of yacc or bison, rather than stuffing your program full of `printf`s which you will later have to delete. Just provide the `-t` option when you run `yacc`, or add

```
#define YYDEBUG 1
```

to the `%{...%}' block in your icg.y file. Then modify your main function:

```
int main() {
  yydebug = 1;
  return yyparse();
}
```

That will tell you exactly what's going on while your input is being parsed, including which terminals are being received from your scanner.

---

Here is a full example showing one approach to memory management. It's based on your code, but with a certain amount of refactoring. Note that the parser *never* copies a string, but `emit_tac` does allocate a new string, as well as freeing the strings it is passed as arguments. (That might be considered rude by some observers.) The call to `yylex_destroy()` in `main` is required for modern `flex`-generated scanners, to free resources allocated by the lexer. The bison-specific `%destructor` prevents memory leaks in case of a syntax error: if you are not using bison, you'll have to find a different solution to that issue.

#### icg.y

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int yylex();
    int yylex_destroy();
    void yyerror(const char* msg);

    int temp_reg_num = 0;
    char* emit_tac(char* text1, char oper, char* text2) {
        char* rv = malloc(8);
        snprintf(rv, 7, "t%d", temp_reg_num++);
        printf("%s = %s %c %s\n", rv, text1 ? text1 : "", oper, text2);
        free(text1); free(text2);
        return rv;
    }
%}

%union {
    char* text;
}
%token <text> IDEN NUMBER
%type <text> e t f x
%destructor { free($$); } <text>

%%
s : IDEN '=' e '\n' { printf("%s = %s\n", $1, $3);
                      free($1); free($3);
                    }
e : e '+' t         { $$ = emit_tac($1,'+',$3); }
  | e '-' t         { $$ = emit_tac($1,'-',$3); }
  | t
t : t '*' f         { $$ = emit_tac($1,'*',$3); }
  | t '/' f         { $$ = emit_tac($1,'/',$3); }
  | f
f : f '^' x         { $$ = emit_tac($1,'^',$3); }
  | x 
x : IDEN 
  | NUMBER
  | '-' x           { $$ = emit_tac(NULL, '-', $2); }
  | '(' e ')'       { $$ = $2; }
%%

int main() {
    int rc = yyparse();
    yylex_destroy();
    return rc;
}

void yyerror(const char* msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}
```

#### icg.l (requires flex)

```
%{
    /* Change to y.tab.h if you use yacc */
    #include "icg.tab.h"
    char* copy_yytext() {
        char* tostring = malloc(yyleng + 1);
        memcpy(tostring, yytext, yyleng);
        tostring[yyleng] = 0;
        return tostring;  
    }
%}
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault

%%

\n                           { return '\n'; }
[[:space:]]                  /* Ignore */
[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit]]*)? { yylval.text = copy_yytext(); return NUMBER;  }
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*    { yylval.text = copy_yytext(); return IDEN; } 
.                            { return yytext[0]; }
```

#### Compile

```
$ bison -d icg.y
$ flex icg.l
$ gcc -Wall -o icg lex.yy.c icg.tab.c
```

#### Test with valgrind to demonstrate absence of memory leaks

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./icg <<< ' x = 1 + 2 - 3 / 4 ^ 5 * ( 6 - 9 )'
==26225== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==26225== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==26225== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==26225== Command: ./icg
==26225== 
t0 = 1 + 2
t1 = 4 ^ 5
t2 = 3 / t1
t3 = 6 - 9
t4 = t2 * t3
t5 = t0 - t4
x = t5
==26225== 
==26225== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26225==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26225==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 17 frees, 16,530 bytes allocated
==26225== 
==26225== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==26225== 
==26225== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==26225== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Great answer! Interesting reading even aside from the context of original question!

Comment: Thanx alot. I still havent tested a case where i put brackets. And thanx alot for my single quotes error.  
About your leaking a copy of the string. I was first doing the way you have suggested. Just allocating the pointer to the string, but then it use throw a lot of segmentation faults. 
When i allocated memory now, it runs safely. But thanx for the <text> syntax. I was unaware of this declaration.

Comment: Also thanx for yydebug comment. Again It is will very useful. And I had no clue about this either. And about the strlen is included in <stdlib.h>, and copy_string method is available in my icg.l file. So I dont need to explicitly declare in my icg.y file. Even if do, it throws an error.

Comment: Yes. Thanx alot. Your suggestion about the newline worked. And i am grateful that you took time to point out all my mistakes and telling me a better way of doing them. Hats Off sir.

Comment: @ishaan: sometimes you have to copy you need to copy yytext, for example, and you obviously couldn't just use the address of a local temporary. (Although your use of a local temporary is pointless; you could malloc the space and then fill it in, without the need for a copy.) You neef to think through each context. By the way, `strdup` exists on most systems.

Comment: Sir, I guess I just played safe. I had really less time to write this code. And I am relatively new to yacc, still dont understand it in detail. I tried whatever you have said. I have altered my code. 

Pointers are not working as you have mentioned. When i write complex expression, some pointers start pointing to same address.

example :  x = 1 + 2 - 3 / 4 ^ 5 * ( 6 - 9 )  Output : t0 = 1 + 2
t1 = 4 ^ 5
t2 = 3 / t1
t3 = 6 - 9
t4 = t3 * t3
t5 = t4 - t4
x = t5

but when i use copy the strings : t0 = 1 + 2
t1 = 4 ^ 5
t2 = 3 / t1
t3 = 6 - 9
t4 = t2 * t3
t5 = t0 - t4
x = t5

Comment: @ishaan: as i said you need to copy `temp` (or create it directly in newly-allocated storage). Only the unit productions don't need copies. In other words, you never need to copy the same string twice.

Comment: @IshaanChawla: There's a complete example, showing one way to manage memory. If this is a homework assignment, I'd appreciate it if you don't submit my work as your answer :)

Comment: Thanx alot sir for the explanation. I was just practicing, wasnt any assignment. :)